# How can i find a specific part of a string?

Tags: python, csv

Im accessing a csv file, looping through all of its rows(strings) and i want too keep / print all parts of each string which start with a "." , has two words in the middle and ends with either a "." "?" or "!".

For example, if the string was: "This is my new channel. Please subscribe!" i'd only want to keep the ". Please subscribe!"

So far i only have this to show me how many words are inside each string:

```
with open("data2.csv", encoding="utf-8", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        rowstr = str(row[1])
        res = len(row[1].split())
        print(res)
```

I've tried:

```
with open("data2.csv", encoding="utf-8", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        rowstr = row[1]
        res = len(row[1].split())
        re.findall(r"\.\S+\s\S+[.?!]", rowstr)
        print(row[1])
```

I get no output from findall, only from printing row[1]

Fixed it

Working code:

```
with open("data2.csv", encoding="utf-8", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        rowstr = row[1]
        res = len(row[1].split())
        finalData = re.findall(r"(\.\W\w+\W\w+[\.\?!])", rowstr)
        print(finalData)
```

Comment: You could use a regular expression.  `r"\.\S+\s\S+[.?!]"`

Comment: That's a pretty strange requirement. Why exactly 2 words?

Comment: `row[1]` is already a string, you don't need to call `str()`

Comment: `rowstr` is not even used anywhere else in the program as well...

Comment: @TimRoberts i've tried implementing this but didnt succeed.
I've updated my post with the code i tried.

Comment: Basically analysing data and trying to find the most common expressions that use 2 words.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```
re.findall(r'(\.\W\w+\W\w+[\.\?!])$',"This is my new channel. Please subscribe!" )
```

which output:
`['. Please subscribe!']`

Comment: I've tried implementing this but didnt succeed. I've updated the post with the code i've tried.

Comment: After a few more tries i've finally got it to work! Thanks a lot! I've also updated the post with the working code.

Comment: If it aswers your question, you can consider accepting the answer!

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is the best solution to the problems like this. Please refer here [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)!

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at it :)